# How to use form validation with the file uploader to make sure a file is uploaded

Tags: forms, validation, codeigniter, frameworks, upload

Can anyone suggest how using the form validation rules I can say the following:-

If no file is uploaded - then create a rule to say 'no file uploaded' using the form validator library.

I am using CodeIgniter 2.

For instance - it is simple to validate on a text input field using the following, but I cannot understand how this is done with upload (that uses the $_FILES array rather than $_POST)

eg.
$this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required'); // input field named 'title' is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter's `File Uploading` class handles its own validation - no need to use the `Form Validation` class.

[Per the documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html),

> **`$this->upload->display_errors()`**
>
> ---
>
> Retrieves any error messages if the `do_upload()` function returned
>   false. The function does not `echo` automatically, it returns the data
>   so you can assign it however you need.

In your example above, if the file input is left empty, `$this->upload->display_errors()` will return the following:

> You did not select a file to upload.

So, set your preferences (see the "Setting Preferences" section of [the documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) for exactly what is available):

```
// The following are just examples from the documentation...
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '100';
$config['max_width'] = '1024';
$config['max_height'] = '768';
// ... other preferences as necessary
```

If any of the above fail during the attempted upload, `$this->upload->display_errors()` will retrieve the appropriate error message. Simply pass it to your view to display the error(s).

Hope that helps.